# Alfresco CMIS Web Scripts API for 'getContent' by path is not working

Tags: alfresco

I have a file in my Alfresco (4.1.5) repository of which I want to read the content through the Alfresco services REST API. 
For the lookup, I want to use the file path, not the UUID. However, the lookup by path does not work, only the lookup by UUID works. I cannot find the mistake.

This is the file path:

DisplayPath & File Name:

```
/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Cleaner Configs/cleaner.properties
```

QNamePath:

```
/app:company_home/app:dictionary/cm:Cleaner_x0020_Configs/cm:cleaner.properties
```

Lookup by UUID works with the following REST API url:

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/i/2391adf9-365c-4959-bf30-8f001154c100/content
```

**However, lookup by path only does not work. Neither with the primary path nor the display path:**

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/p/app:company_home/app:dictionary/cm:Cleaner_x0020_Configs/cm:cleaner.properties/content?a=false

http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/p/Company%20Home/Data%20Dictionary/Cleaner%20Configs/cleaner.properties/content?a=false
```

I am getting a 404 error in both cases:

```
Message:    10080001 Unable to find ObjectPathReference[storeRef=workspace://SpacesStore,path=/app:company_home/app:company_home/app:dictionary/cm:Cleaner_x0020_Configs/cm:cleaner.properties]

Exception:  org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException - 10080001 Unable to find ObjectPathReference[storeRef=workspace://SpacesStore,path=/app:company_home/app:company_home/app:dictionary/cm:Cleaner_x0020_Configs/cm:cleaner.properties]
```

Reference:

http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Web_Scripts_Reference#Get_Content_.28getContent.29

> Gets the content stream for the specified document, or gets a
>   rendition stream for a specified rendition of a document.
>
> GET /alfresco/service/cmis/p{path}/content{property}?a={attach?}

Comment: Taking a look at your error message, I spot `/app:company_home/app:company_home/` in there. Did you really mean to try and find one company home within a second?

Comment: @Gagravarr The duplicate app:company_home was not on purpose. It only appears twice in the error message that I was getting, I did not have it twice in the request url. So I just tried to remove it, calling: http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/p/app:dictionary/cm:Cleaner_x0020_Configs/cm:cleaner.properties/content?a=false - but it also throws a 404 error: Unable to find ObjectPathReference[storeRef=workspace://SpacesStore,path=/app:company_home/app:company_home/app:dictionary/cm:Cleaner_x0020_Configs/cm:cleaner.properties] - where the path is now ok, with only one /app:company_home

Comment: Ok, I found the solution: I have to use the display path, BUT LEAVE OUT /Company Home/ in the path, because it's automatically added before the path. Or in other words, the path is always taken as relative to the /Company Home. This works: http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/p/Data%20Dictionary/Cleaner%20Configs/cleaner.properties/content?a=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, thanks to @Gagravarr for the hint:

I have to use the **display path**, **but leave out /Company%20Home/** in the path, because the path used in the request url is taken as relative to the /Company%20Home node.

This works:

```
http://<host:port>/alfresco/service/cmis/p/Data%20Dictionary/Cleaner%20Configs/cleaner.properties/content?a=false
```

Comment: Note that if using Display Paths, it won't work on a repo that was created in a different language, as Display Paths get localised. You need to use QNames if you want it to be consistent between different languages

Comment: Noted, however as I see it, the qname does not work with the /alfresco/service/cmis/p/ API.